# Add Class objects to Collection using a Function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this class:

```
Option Explicit
Public Code As String
Public ArticleType As String
Public Division As String
Public Devise As String
Public GroupePrix As String
Property Get CodeOnly() As String
    CodeOnly = Replace(Code, "*", "")
End Property
```

And this function:

```
Function addFabricant(cod As String, art As String, div As String, dev As String, grp As String) As Fabricant
    Dim Fab As New Fabricant
    Fab.Code = cod
    Fab.ArticleType = art
    Fab.Division = div
    Fab.Devise = dev
    Fab.GroupePrix = grp
    Set addFabricant = Fab
End Function
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
Set Fabricants = New Collection
'This is where the code fail with error 438
Fabricants.Add (addFabricant("Code", "Sample", " ", "DogeCoin", "420"))
...
```

But it does not work. I'm new to VBA so I may be missing something.

I know that :

```
Set test = addFabricant("Code", "Sample", " ", "DogeCoin", "420")
Fabricants.Add (test)
```

is working, but it would add double the code to add all the `Fabricant` this way.

Comment: Get rid of the extra parens and it should work. `Fabricants.Add addFabricant("Code", "Sample", " ", "DogeCoin", "420")`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's working now. Any clue why the VBA editor (Using Excel 2007) was not giving syntax errors?

Comment: It's technically not a syntax error. It's a runtime error. But it's best to _not_ use parenthesis when calling a sub. `Add()` is a `Sub`. It doesn't return a value. So rather than `Call c.Add(obj)` or `c.Add (obj)`, just use `c.Add obj`. It'll make life easier and prevent these types of runtime errors from occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want "user defined types"

```
Public Type MyType
   MyInt As Integer
   MyString As String
   MyDoubleArr(2) As Double
End Type
```

Then use it as a collection or an array.

```
Dim MyArr(2) As MyType

MyArr(0).MyInt = 31
MyArr(0).MyString = "VBA"
MyArr(0).MyDoubleArr(0) = 1
MyArr(0).MyDoubleArr(1) = 2
MyArr(0).MyDoubleArr(2) = 3
MyArr(1).MyInt = 32
MyArr(1).MyString = "is"
MyArr(1).MyDoubleArr(0) = 11
MyArr(1).MyDoubleArr(1) = 22
MyArr(1).MyDoubleArr(2) = 33
MyArr(2).MyInt = 33
MyArr(2).MyString = "cool"
MyArr(2).MyDoubleArr(0) = 111
MyArr(2).MyDoubleArr(1) = 222
MyArr(2).MyDoubleArr(2) = 333
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using classes for his purposes.

Comment: This approach totally defeats the purpose of implementing the simplicity of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a wrapper class for your collection and add methods to the FabricantCollection to do what you want. Here is a FabricantCollection started for you:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const MODULE_NAME As String = "FabricantCollection"

Private m_oCollection As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_oCollection = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If Not m_oCollection Is Nothing Then
        Set m_oCollection = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Public Function Add(oFabricant As Fabricant) As Long
    m_oCollection.Add oFabricant, oFabricant.Code
    Add = m_oCollection.Count
End Function

Public Sub Clear()
    Set m_oCollection = New BaseCollection
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = m_oCollection.Count
End Property

Public Function Item(ByVal vKey As Variant) As Fabricant
    Set Item = m_oCollection.Item(vKey)
End Function

Public Function Remove(ByVal vKey As Variant) As Fabricant
    Set Remove = m_oCollection.Item(vKey)
    m_oCollection.Remove vKey
End Function

Public Function AddNew( _
        ByVal sCode As String, _
        ByVal sArt As String, _
        ByVal sDiv As String, _
        ByVal sDev As String, _
        ByVal sGrp As String) As Fabricant

    Dim oFabricant As Fabricant
    If Not oFabricant Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 3334, MODULE_NAME & ".AddNew", "Item already exists with that key: " & sCode
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set oFabricant = New Fabricant

    With oFabricant
        .Code = sCode
        .ArticleType = sArt
        .Division = sDiv
        .Devise = sDev
        .GroupePrix = sGrp
    End With

    Add oFabricant

    Set AddNew = oFabricant

End Function

Public Property Get Fabricant( _
        ByVal sCode As String) As Variant

    Set Fabricant = m_oCollection.Item(sCode)

End Property
```